# Cannot find content file in bin folder

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have a IIS Express project running in debug mode in Visual Studio 2015.

The web application references a Class Library which has this line of code:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"certkey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

The certkey.p12 file is in the same folder as the source code for the class library as is marked as "Build Action = Content" and "Copy if newer".

When I build, the file is copied to the web app's bin folder as expected. But when I call the method from the web app, it throws "file not found".

It works fine in Unit Testing where the file is copied to /bin/x64/Debug/

So where is IIS Express looking for the file? I suspect it is some sort of temp folder but why isn't VS copying the file there when I build/debug?

Answer (score 0):

When running under IIS Express, it was looking for is "C:\Programs Files\IIS Express\certkey.p12".

I used a little peeking to find the folder that the file was actually copied to and came up with this:

```
string binPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
Uri uri = new Uri(binPath);
string localPath = uri.LocalPath;
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(localPath);
// now "dir" is the full local path of the bin folder
```

It is a little slow on first execute (~100ms) but faster on subsequent requests.

If there are any problems when I deploy this to production, I'll update.